# WHICH is BETTER > Triggers or TTL

Tags: cassandra, triggers, ttl

I need to know which one is better for performance
TRIGGERS || TTL ?

Or which among st them are more convenient to use.

Comment: Please provide more information - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to first move data to another table if data exceeds 1,000,000 records
and then need to delete that data from another table after 7 days.
I want to the the most efficient way to do so.

Comment: sorry not 1,000,000 records but 25,000 records perday

Answer (score 2):

So while "better" is definitely subjective, what I'll do here is talk about what you need to do to enable both a TTL and a trigger in Cassandra.  Then you can decide for yourself.

To implement a TTL, you need to modify the `default_time_to_live` property on your table to a value (in seconds) starting from write-time to when that data should be deleted.  It defaults to zero (`0`), which effectively disables TTL for that table.  The following CQL will set a TTL of 7 days:

```
ALTER TABLE my_keyspace_name.my_table_name WITH default_time_to_live = 604800;
```

Do note that TTL'd data still creates tombstones, so be careful of that.  It works best for time series use cases, where data is clustered by a `timestamp`/`timeUUID` in `DESC`ending order.  The descending order part is key, as that keeps your tombstones at the "bottom" of the partition, so queries for recent data should never encounter them.

Implementing a trigger is somewhat more complex.  For starters, you'll need to write a class which `implements` the `ITrigger` interface.  That class will also need to overload the `augment` method, like this:

```
public class MyTrigger implements ITrigger {
    public Collection<RowMutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update)
```

Inside that method, you'll want to grab the table and keyspace names from the `update` metadata, build your `DELETE` statement:

```
{
    String keyspace = update.metadata().ksName;
    String table = update.metadata().cfName;

    StringBuilder strCQLHeader = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM ")
        .append(keyspace)
        .append(".")
        .append(table)
        .append(" WHERE ");
```

...As well as some logic to grab the key values to delete/move and anything else you'd need to do here.

Next, you'll need to build that class into a JAR and copy it to the `$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/triggers/` dir.

Then (yep, not done yet) you'll need to add that trigger class to your table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON my_table_name USING 'com.yourcompany.packagename.MyTrigger';
```

While you're free to choose whichever works best for you, I *highly* recommend using a TTL.  Implementing triggers in Cassandra is one of those things that tends to be on a "crazy" level of difficulty.

Comment: I'd like to add to Aaron's excellent answer that compatibility between major versions of triggers are not guaranteed and something might break if you do a major upgrade without some refactoring.